# Session timeout in Java EE

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, weblogic, session-timeout

In which ways the time for session timeout can be defined in Java EE? I am looking beyond obvious ways, such as setting session timeout in web.xml or HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval().

I am currently reviewing a Java EE application, but I can't find anything related to session timeout definition. The web app is in Weblogic. I am assuming that since there is no session timeout definition, the session will never expire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're looking for how the session can be timed out in Weblogic, I can add

`TimeoutSecs` in `weblogic.xml` or check for any point in the code where session is killed by `session.invalidate()` on logout.

By the way, it will not be infinite.

On Weblogic, the default in web.xml (if no value specified) is to use the `TimeoutSecs` value in weblogic.xml, which [defaults to 3600 secs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/weblogic_xml.html) i.e. 60 mins

Comment: Saw that towards the end of a long day and thought I was losing my mind.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Not Spring related:

- Control the [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) yourself by `response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookiestring);`. It's the `expires` attribute which controls the session timeout. This overrides any servletcontainer or `web.xml` defaults, but is overrideable by [`HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29) in Java code anyway.
- Configure a default at servletcontainer level. In Tomcat for example, by `maxInactiveInterval` attribute of [`<manager>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html) element. This is overrideable by `<session-timeout>` in `web.xml` and [`HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29) in Java code anyway.

---

**Update** as per the comment and question update:

When not specified, then a servletcontainer-managed default timeout will be used. This is usually 30 minutes (which is true for Tomcat and clones). This way the session will expire 30 minutes after the last request sent by the client in the session. Also, when the client closes and reopens the browser instance or clears the cookies, then a new session will be created (the old session will be expired after the default 30 minutes timeout).

Comment: The server timeout is different from the client timeout. Or i didn't get the question :-)

Comment: @Bozho: If the session is timed out on server, then the client won't be able to access the same session anyway, and vice versa.

Comment: I am reviewing the code. I checked the cookies as well, but they don't have an "expires" attribute. The application server used is Weblogic.

Comment: So this question is after all a facade for a concrete problem which you're struggling with? Why not just post a question about the problem directly? As to the `expires` attribute, this is by default omitted (which means that the server side session expires as per server configured default (30 mins usually) or when the client closes/restarts browser).

Comment: You are right, I apologize for not being specific enough from the beginning. I am going to edit the question to what it should have been phrased like. (I have found a solution to the problem, but the way it was initially stated, it implied false assumptions, so it would be virtually impossible for someone to provide the answer I was looking for).

Comment: OK, in the future try to be more specific.